# "There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}" - only for byte arrays in WSDL

Tags: jaxb

This question is with regards to this WSDL (replace _ with "." - can't use IP address as link here):
`https://46.30.8.63/indeni4it/MainFunctionsHandlerService?wsdl`

I run wsimport on it successfully. When I try to call the web service I get the exception below. Interestingly, the exception highlights 6 fields from the WSDL - all of which are byte arrays (for transferring binary content).

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Note that this WSDL loads flawlessly with other environments (.NET, etc.).

Note that I've replaced the name of the company whose WSDL this is with "myco" in the exception text. Just to avoid search engines pulling the name up.

> Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:156)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:84)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:234)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:673)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:661)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:330)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:313)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:295)
>       at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
>       at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.MainFunctionsHandlerService.getMainFunctionsHandlerPort(MainFunctionsHandlerService.java:68)
>       at com.myco.Main.main(Main.java:19)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
>   Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 6 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}return.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.GetBlobDataResponse._return
>           at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.GetBlobDataResponse
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}signatureBytes.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UpdateSystemUsingBlob.signatureBytes
>           at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UpdateSystemUsingBlob
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}licenseData.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UploadNewLicense.licenseData
>           at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UploadNewLicense
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}packageFileBytes.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UpdateSystem.packageFileBytes
>           at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UpdateSystem
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}signatureBytes.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UpdateSystem.signatureBytes
>           at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UpdateSystem
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}content.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.AppendBlobData.content
>           at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.AppendBlobData

```
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:143)
... 15 more
```

> Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 6 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}return.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.GetBlobDataResponse._return
>           at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.GetBlobDataResponse
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}signatureBytes.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UpdateSystemUsingBlob.signatureBytes
>           at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UpdateSystemUsingBlob
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}licenseData.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UploadNewLicense.licenseData
>           at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UploadNewLicense
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}packageFileBytes.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UpdateSystem.packageFileBytes
>           at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UpdateSystem
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}signatureBytes.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UpdateSystem.signatureBytes
>           at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.UpdateSystem
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}content.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.AppendBlobData.content
>           at com.myco.singlesensor.glassfish.AppendBlobData

```
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:450)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:282)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:125)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1147)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:173)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:95)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:98)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:151)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:143)
... 17 more
```

> Process finished with exit code 1